# XPath Select all nodes but not `figure` node

Tags: xml, selenium, xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm scraping articles from **Britannica** websites using `scrapy` framework and `python 3.7.9`.

Here are the links:
[link1](https://www.britannica.com/place/Orlando-Florida)
[link2](https://www.britannica.com/place/Gadsden)

I'm using XPath `//section[@id='ref1'] //descendant::node()/text()` expression to get all text and also text of `figure` nodes which can be selected by `//figure/descendant::node()`.

I want to write an expression to get all the nodes except all `figure` and its `descendants`.

Here what I tried

`//section[@id='ref1'] //descendant::node()[not(@figure[descendant::node()])]`

But not working.

Comment: *"I'm scraping articles from Britannica websites"* Do you have their permission? https://corporate.britannica.com/termsofuse.html

Comment: check `robot.txt` https://www.britannica.com/robots.txt

Comment: Also "You may display, reproduce, print or download content on the Services only for your personal, non-commercial use." in the *Use of Content* Section.

Comment: I read: "*You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on the Services, except with our express written permission."* Without such permission you are asking us to assist you in violating their terms of use and potentially criminal activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do:

```
//section[@id='ref1']//*[not(self::figure)]
```

Comment: I tried but I'm still selecting text from `figure` and its `descendants`.
Is something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
//section[@id='ref1']//descendant::node()[not(name()="figure")]
```

you can access tagname as name()

### update:

if you don't want child elements of figure then use:

```
//section[@id='ref1']//descendant::node()[not(name()="figure") and not(ancestor::figure)]
```

Comment: I tried but I'm still selecting text from `figure` and its `descendants`.
Is something I'm missing?

Comment: @Haseeb your question didn't specify that , updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write an expression to get all the nodes except all figure
> and its descendants.

It seems from the text of the question that you actually want ***all text nodes*** that are descendents of `section[@id='ref1']` ***except*** those that are descendents of any `figure` elements.

One XPath expression that selects these nodes is:

```
//section[@id='ref1']//*[not(self::figure)]/text()
```

Comment: I tried but I'm still selecting text from `figure` and its `descendants`.
Is something I'm missing?

Comment: @Haseeb, Please, edit your question and publish a complete (but minimal) XML document on which the XPath expression in this answer, when evaluated, produces text-node descendents of a `<figure>` element. This could happen if the `figure` element is in a namespace -- but you didn't mention any namespaces...